# example fork(), c lang

Tags: c, fork

I am learning about `fork()` and I am trying to understand this example that I found. From what I think I understand, we always use a different process for each call, both for `fibonacci(n-1)` and `fibonacci(n-2)`; `pid1` is suspended with `waitpid()` to save the last exit status of the child in fib. The same thing happens with `pid2`, and in the end, the return value of the last 2 processes are added together. Is it fair when said?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

size_t fibonacci( size_t n )
{
    pid_t pid1, pid2;
    size_t fib;
    int status;

    switch (n)
    {
    case 0:
        return 0;
    case 1:
        return 1;
    case 2:
        return 1;
    default:
        break;
    }

    pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 == 0)
        exit( fibonacci( n - 1 ));           // chiamo fibonacci(n-1) usando pid1
    else if (pid1 < 0)
    {
        printf("ERRORE");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid2 = fork();

    if (pid2 == 0)
        exit( fibonacci( n - 2 ));          // chiamo fibonacci(n-1) usando pid2
    else if (pid2 < 0)
    {
        printf("ERRORE");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (waitpid( pid1, &status, 0 ) == -1) // sospende pid1
    {
        printf("ERRORE");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fib = WEXITSTATUS( status ); // salvo in fib lo stato di uscita del figlio di pid1

    if (waitpid( pid2, &status, 0 ) == -1)  // sospendo pid2
    {
        printf("ERRORE");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return fib + WEXITSTATUS( status ); // recupero valori di ritorno dei processi
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (a > 0 && a < 10)
    {
        printf("Calcolo fibonacci di %d \n", a);

        printf("L' %so numero di Fibonacci e' %d.\n", argv[1], fibonacci(a));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Devi inserire un numero compreso tra 1 e 10\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to read this help page: [How to create a minimal reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) The comments and the output of your program are not in English.

Comment: As you learn about this more, do try and grasp what a terrible idea it is to fork *two* processes . When computing `fib(n)` as `fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)`, forking *both* of those and then summarily sitting there doing nothing while they complete should be a giant red flag telling you rather than forking two and waiting, how about forking *one* and then *working*. I.e. `fib(n)` forks *once* to compute `fib(n-2)`, directly call `fib(n-1)` and store the result, wait on the forked process to complete, adds to the stored value and returns it as the overall result. Think about that.

Comment: Note that on Unix systems, the exit status is normally limited to the range 0..255 — you have to work a lot harder to get bigger values relayed to the parent (`sigaction()`, `SA_SIGINFO`, etc).  That limits how big the numbers can be.  You should be OK up to 10, though.

Comment: What you describe is a mostly accurate description of how the code works. It isn't good to make the code work like that — it involves a lot of processes for no real benefit.  But as an illustration of using `fork()` and `waitpid()`, it does work.  One way of checking the operation is to add diagnostic printing, so you know about which processes are created and their exit status.  Note that if a child exits with `EXIT_FAILURE`, the parent gets the value `1` to add to the sum.  You might want to have the child commit seppuku with `kill(getpid(), SIGINT)` or some signal so you can spot the error.

Comment: In order to learn about how `fork()` works, you should not use a recursive problem to test it.  You need proficiency in two different fields to understand the whole thing, and you are  having problems also in the recursive part of the problem.  By the way, the problems of `fork()` are more in connecting processes and let them talk to each other (handling redirections), which is something you seem not having faced yet.